# How to select benefactors that have not made contributions in the last year (SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a simple database that keeps track of contributions (donations) to a charitable organisation.

For the purposes of this question, I only need mention the two tables involved: `contributions` and `benefactors`.

**Benefactors:**

```
ID | BenefactorName | AssociatedFundraiser | Other Meta Columns
-------------------------------------------------------------------
99 | ABC Accounting | 12                   | ...
```

**Contributions:**

```
ID  | ContributionDate | BenefactorID | Other Meta Columns
--------------------------------------------------------------
603 | 2014-09-29       | 99           | ...
```

Many of the benefactors in this database make contributions more than once; mostly on a monthly basis. However, I'd like to pin point the benefactors who have not made a contribution in the last year.

How do I go about doing that?

I have tried various `INNER JOIN` stuff, but was way off-track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Access doesn't support the `MINUS` set operator, things can be a little confusing in situations like this. I think a query such as this would meet your needs:

```
SELECT v.ID, v.[Benefactor Name], v.MaxContributionDate
FROM (
    SELECT b.ID, b.[Benefactor Name], mx.MaxContributionDate
    FROM benefactors b
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MAX([Contribution Date]) AS MaxContributionDate, [Benefactor ID]
        FROM contributions
        GROUP BY [Benefactor ID]
    ) mx ON (mx.[Benefactor ID] = b.ID)
) v
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Benefactor ID]
    FROM contributions
    WHERE Year([Contribution Date]) = 2014
) t ON (t.[Benefactor ID] = v.ID) 
WHERE t.[Benefactor ID] IS NULL;
```

The "in line" query finds the distinct list of benefactors who have made contributions for this year, and the `LEFT JOIN` where the key `IS NULL` ensures that we only return benefactors which are ***not*** in this set.

**edit:** added an extra join to fetch the most recent contribution date for each benefactor.

Comment: This is the first one I've tried - seems to work perfectly. :) But, to double check, how can I add a column that contains the date of their last contribution?

Comment: Thanks - shall try shortly :)

Comment: Something's not right here - it says that there's a missing operator near `(t.BenefactorID = b.ID)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(c2.ContributionDate) AS ContributionDate, c2.BenefactorID
    FROM contributions c2
    GROUP BY c2.BenefactorID
) mx ON (mx.BenefactorID = b.ID)
WHERE t.BenefactorID IS NULL`

Comment: @MikeAnthony - I can't see anything obviously wrong I'm afraid and I don't have Access installed, so I can't easily check it myself :( does the following query work (basically removed the left join)?: `SELECT b.ID, b.BenefactorName, mx.ContributionDate
FROM benefactors b
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(c2.ContributionDate) AS ContributionDate, c2.BenefactorID
    FROM contributions c2
    GROUP BY c2.BenefactorID
) mx ON (mx.BenefactorID = b.ID)`

Comment: It asks me to input a value for `mx.ContributionDate` when I run the query, and when I do, it returns all benefactors who made contributions on that date.

Comment: Could this have anything to do with column names that contain spaces? I realised after answers started coming in that most of my column names are actually two words, such as `Benefactor Name`.

Comment: I think you need to put them in square brackets, like `[Benefactor Name]` if they contain spaces

Comment: @MikeAnthony - OK, so I installed Access and fixed the query, it's not pretty, and I don't really understand why Access didn't like it before, but it works now. I think Access has some quirks relating to multiple join clauses being side-by-side, but hiding the first one inside the inline view `v` seems to fool it into working as I intended.

Comment: thank you for taking the time do that; really do appreciate it. I'll check it out when I get to the office later today. I'm sure it'll work now. :)

Comment: Hi - as we were closing down for the year, I didn't get a chance. I do have a demo database here at home, though. I'll work with it later today or tomorrow.

Comment: I know it's been an incredibly long time, but I do want to confirm that this did actually work when I used it. The only change I made was to change `WHERE Year([Contribution Date]) = 2014` to `WHERE [Contribution Date] > #yyyy/mm/dd#` - I obviously used the date I wanted to get the correct results. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.*
FROM Benefactors b
INNER JOIN Contributions c ON b.id = c.BenefactorID
WHERE c.ContributionDate < DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
```

Comment: pretty sure this is not quite right - it looks like it will return benefactors who have made a contribution before this year, irrespective of whether or not they made a contribution this year. It will also return the same benefactor multiple times if they have made more than one contribution.

Comment: He only wants to see benefactors who have contributed BEFORE this year, `How to select benefactors that have not made contributions in the last year` and it has the contribution date so there would be no confusion. I would also assume that he wants to see all contributions as it was a plural in the title.

Comment: If I, as a benefactor, made contributions on 2013/01/01 and 2014/06/04, then your query would currently return one row for the 2013 contribution. All that's doing is tell you which contributions were not made this year, it doesn't tell you whether or not I made any _other_ contributions _this_ year.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM benefactors AS b
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM contributions AS c 
       WHERE b.ID = c.benefactorID 
             AND c.ContributionDate < DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
      ) = 0
```

Comment: in databases with large volumes of data I think this query would be inefficient - Access would execute the inner query for every benefactor, which could be expensive

Comment: `GETDATE()` is not available in Access. If I change it to `NOW()`, then it asks me for the value for `year`, and then says the expression is typed incorrectly, or is to complex to process.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN.`

To get the list of Benefactors who are not contributed for the last one year.

```
SELECT A.* FROM Benefactors AS B 
LEFT JOIN Contributions AS C 
ON B.ID  = C.BenefactorID  AND C.BenefactorID IS NULL 
WHERE C.ContributionDate < DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
   select * from Benefactors b where b.ID not in  (select BenefactorID  from Contributions where  datepart(yy,ContributionDate)=datepart(yy,getdate())-1 )
```

OR

```
 select * from Benefactors b inner join  (select * from Contributions where  datepart(yy,ContributionDate)=datepart(yy,getdate())-1 ) a on b.ID<>a.BenefactorID
```

Comment: in databases with large volumes of data I think this query would be inefficient - Access would execute the inner query for every benefactor, which could be expensive

Answer (score 0):

When you want to select the list of Benefactors who didn't made any contribution for the last year (**when current year = 2014 then last year = 2013**) Try the below code:

```
SELECT * FROM Benefactors 
WHERE ID NOT IN
 (SELECT BenefactorID FROM Contributions 
 WHERE DATEPART(yyyy, ContributionDate)  >
       DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(year,-2,GETDATE()))
 AND DATEPART(yyyy, ContributionDate) < DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE())
```

Comment: in databases with large volumes of data I think this query would be inefficient - Access would execute the inner query for every benefactor, which could be expensive